# Set execution order for the gRPC ServerInterceptors

Tags: java, spring, grpc, grpc-java

In io.grpc.internal.AbstractServerImplBuilder you may add implementations of the ServerInterceptor to the final list

```
final List<ServerInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
```

then in default server implementation for the builder - io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl it calls them in the foreach loop

```
/** Never returns {@code null}. */
private <ReqT, RespT> ServerStreamListener startCall(ServerStream stream, String fullMethodName,
    ServerMethodDefinition<ReqT, RespT> methodDef, Metadata headers,
    Context.CancellableContext context, StatsTraceContext statsTraceCtx, Tag tag) {
  // TODO(ejona86): should we update fullMethodName to have the canonical path of the method?
  statsTraceCtx.serverCallStarted(
      new ServerCallInfoImpl<>(
          methodDef.getMethodDescriptor(), // notify with original method descriptor
          stream.getAttributes(),
          stream.getAuthority()));
  ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> handler = methodDef.getServerCallHandler();
  for (ServerInterceptor interceptor : interceptors) {
    handler = InternalServerInterceptors.interceptCallHandler(interceptor, handler);
  }
  ServerMethodDefinition<ReqT, RespT> interceptedDef = methodDef.withServerCallHandler(handler);
  ServerMethodDefinition<?, ?> wMethodDef = binlog == null
      ? interceptedDef : binlog.wrapMethodDefinition(interceptedDef);
  return startWrappedCall(fullMethodName, wMethodDef, stream, headers, context, tag);
}
```

so it executes the interceptors chain from the last registered to the former one when received the request.
Same order is followed when doing the response from the handler.

What I wonder and expected is that it will follow onion middleware pattern and you can explicitly set the execution order (similar to the servlet filters).
Do I miss something?

Comment: No, you cannot set the execution order as the javadoc states.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to set the order. `ServerBuilder.intercept()` is a convenience version of `ServerInterceptors.intercept()`, and follows the same semantics. There is `ServerInterceptors.interceptForward()` which runs them in the opposite direction, but you can't have an API that adds interceptors individually and support both forms simultaneously.

The intercept API is a bit confusing because it *does* follow the onion principal, but the onion is around the *service*. Interceptors wrap a *service*, and so the last interceptor applied is executed first.

```java
serviceDef = ServerInterceptors.intercept(serviceDef,
    interceptor1,
    interceptor2,
    interceptor3);

// is equivalent to

serviceDef = ServerInterceptors.intercept(serviceDef, interceptor1);
serviceDef = ServerInterceptors.intercept(serviceDef, interceptor2);
serviceDef = ServerInterceptors.intercept(serviceDef, interceptor3);
// the gRPC server sees the last 'serviceDef', so interceptor3 is
// called first
```